¿Por qué se crea la carpeta ZY725G~0 en mi proyecto Laravel y cómo solucionarlo?
En mi proyecto Laravel, dentro de la carpeta public, se ha generado un directorio con el nombre ZY725G~0, y dentro de él, un archivo laravel.log. Esto no debería suceder, ya que los logs normalmente se almacenan en storage/logs/. ¿Cómo puedo corregir este comportamiento para que los logs se guarden en la ruta correcta?


Que estás usando para crear logs? Dentro del archivo logs, hay datos específicos que apunten al archivo que genera el log ?

Puedes intentar con esto
channels' => [
    'stack' => [
        'driver' => 'stack',
        'channels' => ['single'],
        'ignore_exceptions' => false,
    ],

    'single' => [
        'driver' => 'single',
        'path' => storage_path('logs/laravel.log'),
        'level' => env('LOG_LEVEL', 'debug'),
    ],
],

Después, concede permisos de escritura a storage/logs:
chmod -R 775 storage/logs/

Reinicia el servidor para realizar exitosamente los cambios.
Explicación del código:
Se crean dos canales para logging, el primero sería "stack", que usa el driver "stack" para combinar varios canales de logging. Especifica que el canal "stack" usará el canal "single" y que registrará las excepciones. El segundo canal es "single", que usará el driver correspondiente y guardará los logs en el directorio deseado. Por último, se definirá el nivel en cualquiera de las variables especificadas.
Espero haberte ayudado, la verdad no soy mucho de este tema.
